# Load VSPackage with dynamic items did not load on startup

Tags: dynamic, load, visual-studio-2019, vspackage

I have a Visual Studio Package where items are dynamically added to the menu bar. However, only the fixed entries are shown because the extension is not loaded correctly.
The package is only loaded when you click on a fixed entry. But it should be loaded at the start of the studio.
I tried everything with ProvideAutoLoad, the dynamic items are not shown. I don't know why. What is the problem ?

I hope someone can help me here

thx

Answer (score 2):

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
```

should be enough to automatically load a package on Visual Studio startup.

Comment: The package does not load automatically at startup. Not even with the two PrivateAutoLoad attributes. The Initialize method is only called when I click on a fixed entry in the submenu. Is it even due to Visual Studio 2019? With the VS 2017 it still worked. Can you think of anything else that could be the reason?

Comment: @flipfine Please share your full Package class declaration.

Comment: Here the Package class declaration

Comment: @flipfine Inheriting from Package is deprecated in VS 2019. You should inherit from AsyncPackage. And PackageRegistration should include AllowsBackgroundLoading: [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)] See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-asyncpackage-to-load-vspackages-in-the-background?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have another question. You seem to know yourself well.
Is it possible to add different icons to dynamic command items? Unfortunately I have not found anything to do that.

Comment: @flipfine You probably can't. But you can add multiple items with different icons and dynamically hide and show items with unneeded/needed icons. (And it is best to open a separate question instead of comments if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VSIXOpenSCE
{   
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
    [InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)] // Info on this package for Help/About
    [SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1650:ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly", Justification = "pkgdef, VS and vsixmanifest are valid VS terms")]
    [ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
    [Guid(MenuControlPackage.PackageGuidString)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
    public sealed class MenuControlPackage : Package
    {
        
        public const string PackageGuidString = "f5c6cb4a-bb86-48e4-92e6-f0ee6de2de3a";

       
        public MenuControlPackage()
        {            
            // Inside this method you can place any initialization code that does not require
            // any Visual Studio service because at this point the package object is created but
            // not sited yet inside Visual Studio environment. The place to do all the other
            // initialization is the Initialize method.
        }

        #region Package Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialization of the package; this method is called right after the package is sited, so this is the place
        /// where you can put all the initialization code that rely on services provided by VisualStudio.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {          
            base.Initialize();          
            MenuControl.Initialize(this);           
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```